# Abbreviating pathname prefixes from the output of git log --stat

Tags: git, git-log

When I run `git log --stat` on a repository where most of the changes are occurring in the same subtree deep in the hierarchy, I may get something like this:

```
$ git log --stat
commit xxxxxxx
Author: xxx
Date:   xxx

    commit message

.../toplevel/networking/services/cool_analysis/Makefile    |  10 ++
.../networking/services/cool_analysis/cool_analysis_main.c | 209 +++............
.../subdirectory/util/cool_analysis_helper.c               | 112 +++.......
```

where everything shares the common prefix `xxx/toplevel/networking/services/cool_analysis` (and `subdirectory` is runder that) but the output of `git log --stat` makes it really hard to recognize the fact, because different amounts of the pathname prefixes are abbreviated. Instead I would like something like this:

```
$ git log --stat --strip=xxx/toplevel/networking/services/cool_analysis
commit xxxxxxx
Author: xxx
Date:   xxx

    commit message

.../Makefile                                 |  10 ++
.../cool_analysis_main.c                     | 209 +++............
.../subdirectory/util/cool_analysis_helper.c | 112 +++.......
```

Is there a way to get this? The manual doesn't seem to have anything about it, and post-processing the output with `sed` or something is hard because the pathnames are already abbreviated. (`git log --name-only` gives unabbreviated full pathnames, but it doesn't give you the stats.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
git log --stat --oneline --relative=[path]
```

> ***`--relative[=<path>]`***
>
> When run from a ***`subdirectory`*** of the project, it can be told to **exclude** changes outside the directory and show pathnames relative to it with this option. When you are not in a subdirectory (e.g. in a bare repository), you can name which subdirectory to make the output relative to by giving a  as an argument.

---

Here are 2 screenshots with the differences.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't `--relative` cover it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--relative` parameter for this.

```
git log --stat --relative=xxx/toplevel/networking/services/cool_analysis
```

If you're in the correct directory already, you don't need to provide the path to `--relative`.